# What is the possible reason that cause the failure (burnt) of PTC in an electronic ballast?

Tags: power-electronics, light, ptc, ballast, electronic-ballast

What is the possible reason that might cause the failure (burnt) of PTC in an electronic ballast?

I have been using this VOSSLOH SCHWABE brand electronic ballast and recently it has been burning up after several years of usage. When I investigate closely, I discovered that the PTC on the ballast is burnt beyond recognition but the rest of the circuit looks intact.

And it seems to be common occurrence as every few month the ballast will fail and every failed ballast has their PTC burnt.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: PTC devices are intended to run hot; that means they might look bad, but still function normally.   An exploded capacitor, though, is definitely failed, and might indicate AC power surges, or a 'floating neutral' in some wiring schemes.

Comment: maybe the tubes were getting too old and not striking. Thus the current through the heaters caused the PTC to overheat. Or the PTCs are old due to repeated stresses and get a hotspot then fail.